# Is the result of my feature encoding numeric or categorical?

Tags: feature-engineering, feature-extraction, encoding, one-hot-encoding

I have the following categorical feature in a data table (recording the day of week when a certain action happened):

```
ID | DAY_OF_WEEK
---+-------------
01 | MON
01 | TUE
02 | MON
01 | MON
01 | WED
02 | SAT
02 | SUN
```

I have turned these into different columns according to days of week and proportion (percent) of events happening that days respectively per ID:

```
ID | MON_% | TUE_% | WED% | THU_% | FRI_% | SAT_% | SUN_%
---+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+------
01 | 0.50  | 0.25  | 0.25 | 0.0   | 0.0   | 0.0   | 0.0
02 | 0.33  | 0.0   | 0.0  | 0.0   | 0.0   | 0.33  | 0.33
```

Now, my question is if the latter resulted encoding matters as quasi one-hot encoded features or rather numerical features? This does matter because applying K-Means or computing (Euclidean) distances are invalid on OHE while valid on numerical features. I'm uncertain.

Comment: If the features are the percentage values, these are clearly numerical.

Comment: Well, OHE-encoding values are also "numerical" values themselves, so it's not so evident for me.

Comment: No, this is different: one applies OHE to categorical values in order to convert them to numerical representation. categorical values have a finite set of values and no order. Percentages are numerical since the number is infinite (e.g. 0.00001%) and there is an order.

Comment: The result of the encoding is always numerical, what matters is whether the source feature is categorical or numerical.